# Am I implementing a heap-based priority queue correctly? Is downheap necessary?

Tags: java, heap, semantics

I believe I just correctly completed the following assignment:

> Implement a heap ­based priority queue class using the vector representation, containing characters.

My program compiles and when implemented for the remainder of the assignment I achieved all of the desired outputs. My question is whether I actually implemented the heap correctly. My teacher identified three key methods for a heap-based queue: downheap, upheap, and extractMin.

```
public static void upheap(int j)
    {

            int p = parent(j);
            if(heap.get(j) < heap.get(p)) { swap(j,p); }
            if (j == 0) return;
            upheap(p);
    }
public static char extractRoot()
    {
            if (heap.size() == 0)
                    return 0;
            char root = heap.get(0);
            heap.set(0,heap.get(heap.size() - 1));
            heap.remove(heap.size() - 1);
            downheap(0);
            return root;
    }
public static void downheap(int j)
    {
            if(hasLeft(j))
            {
                    int smallerIndex = left(j);
                    if(hasRight(j) && heap.get(right(j)) < heap.get(left(j)))
                            smallerIndex = right(j);
                    if(heap.get(j) > heap.get(smallerIndex))
                    {
                            swap(j, smallerIndex);
                    }
                    upheap(j);
                    downheap(smallerIndex);
            }
    }
```

However, I feel like my downheap function is just piggybacking off of upheap, and actually entirely unnecessary. I have the function:

```
public static void add(char c)
{
    heap.add(c);
    upheap(heap.size() - 1);
}
```

(where heap is an ArrayList) and that automatically makes sure that every new entry follows the heap-order property. I never actually end up using downheap to sort anything - so is there any point to even keep it in the class? When would I use it?

If anyone wants to see the rest of the methods in the class I'll post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can remove the call to upheap() in your downheap() method. 
As you know the root in a priority queue heap is highest priority element.
The downheap method comes into picture only when the highest priority element is removed i.e. the root element is swapped with the last element. In your case the extractRoot() method. Once you extractRoot() all the the other elements in the heap would satisfy the heap property except the one on root. 
Also when you are moving the root element down you are swapping with the smaller value i.e swap(j, smallerIndex). Hence there would never be a case when you would need to move an element up the heap in case of downheap().

To answer your question, when you call add() downHeap() is useless but when you call extractMin() downheap() is necessary.

[Heap Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaY1b.jpg)

Comment: thanks a ton! totally forgot about its importance in extractMin()